# Multiplication operation in Java is resulting in negative value

Tags: java

Why does the below calculation produce a negative value?

```
long interval = 0;

interval = ((60000 * 60) * 24) * 30;
```

Comment: Break the calculation apart into several steps and track it in the debugger.  That should demonstrate where it goes wrong more clearly.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Every expression in there is being evaluated (at compile-time, of course; it's a constant) as `int * int` instead of `long * long`. The result overflows at some point. So just use `L` to make all the operand literals long:

```
interval = ((60000L * 60L) * 24L) * 30L;
```

Of course you could get away with only making *some* of the operands longs, but I tend to find it's easier to just change everything.

Having said all of this, if you're looking for "30 days-worth of milliseconds" it would be better to use:

```
long interval = TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(30);
```

Answer (score 3):

Because the value of the equation is causing a number so big that it wraps around It will result in a Integer.
[Int](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html)

Answer (score 3):

Try this, it won't be negative:

```
long interval = 0;

interval = ((60000L * 60L) * 24L) * 30L;
```

Comment: @Prashant Bhate - just copied OP's code :) `interval = 0;` is not at all required.

Answer (score 3):

Your value is 2592000000 which is bigger than the maximum signed integer value 2^31 (2147483648).  This is called integer overflow, the result overflows into negative.