# Java long strange result

Tags: java

I'm sure it's not strange, rather I didn't understand the docs, but why does:

```
long myLong = 3600*24*365*70;
System.out.println(String.valueOf(myLong));
```

display `-2087447296` when that is clearly not the result of 3600*24*365*70?

Comment: this might help 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6332392/multiplication-operation-in-java-is-resulting-in-negative-value

Comment: Integer overflow happening there. Make any  one of them to long. That saves you from stop happening integer multiplication.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try

```
long myLong = 3600L*24*365*70;
```

as your code is multiplying as int and then converting to a Long. The value as an int is overflowing the max value for an int, but will be OK as a long.